# Concatenation of Boolean and Int

Tags: java, string, boolean, primitive

Why can't i do this?
I understand that concatenation of a int and a string or with boolean,(true or false) is possible, but not an addition of boolean with an int.

What exactly happens when u add a int with a boolean? Why does it show an error?

```
System.out.println(a.length() + a.startsWith("a"));
```

i also understand that the work around for this code is

```
System.out.println(""+a.length() + a.startsWith("a"));
```

which uses concatenation.

Comment: That's not a workaround. That's the correct way to do what you want to do.

Comment: There is no standard definition of what a `boolean` or a `Boolean` and an `int` should do. For String it is just a convenice method.

Comment: @zubergu, using `(""+a.lenght())` it's not only a wrong way to do it, but also a really ugly workaround.

Comment: @zubergu, that *is* a workaround, it's forcing Java to interpret the expression as a string but it's not clear what the intent is. There are better ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the + operation has different functions.

In the first example you try Number + Boolean. And this doesn't make sense, so the compiler gives an error.

In the second example you try String + Number (which is allow as String - concentation and returns a String). Afterwards you try String + boolean (which is also allowed)

Comment: Yes. Java knows that you are performing an arithmetic operation when you do a + operation on two numbers (integers, doubles, etc). Java also knows you are performing a concatenation when you have two Strings against a + operation. Like Denis said though, Number + Boolean is not immediately obvious and so Java throws an error indicating you need to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly happens when u add a int with a boolean? Why does it show an error?

Because the `+` operator is not defined for those operands.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Boolean.toString()` static method to get a string representation of the Boolean value:

```
Boolean.toString(a.startsWith("a"));
```